# returning the LINESTRING of the part of a POLYGON that falls within another POLYGON?

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial, mysql-8.0, spatial-query

I can see if two POLYGON's intersect with one another using [MBRIntersects(g1, g2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_mbrintersects) but is there a way to return the LINESTRING part of
*g1* that falls within *g2*?

Alternatively, if I could get the POINTs of POLYGON *g1* that fall within POLYGON *g2* it seems like I could create a LINESTRING from that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you'd extract separate points or segments from your polygon, check each one against another polygon, then reconstruct needed linestring(s). If you need the output linestring to be in completely then you must check by segments and check that each segment have no intersection with the border.

Comment: As a side note: MBR-functions check the bounding rectangle of the polygon, not the 2 polygons. E.g. the lines may not cross, but their MBR might overlap.